# Charging 2x Li-on 18650 Batteries In Series

Tags: battery-charging, series

I am on a battery powered project where i use 2x18650 batteries connected in series.

I bought this specific module [2S Li-ion Lithium Battery 18650 Charger Protection Board Module](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/2S-Li-ion-Lithium-Battery-18650-Charger-Protection-Board-Module-3A-7-4V-8-4V-New/32642160380.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_0,searchweb201602_2_10057_10056_10065_10055_10054_10069_301_10059_10033_10058_10032_10017_10070_10060_10061_10052_10062_10053_10050_10051,searchweb201603_4&btsid=4efed44c-3531-4ea7-bef8-a59152a3035e)

What kind of charger do i use for this?Could i solder usb connections to charge the series through this module with 5v?

I admit i don't really know how this module works.Does it isolate each battery to completely charge it and the move on to the next?

Comment: I wouldn't even trust it to charge one battery. Reason: No data sheet and untrustworthy source.

Comment: I keep trying to find info all over the net the past days about this but nothing.I asked the seller for more info but he hasn't answered yet.

Comment: Golden rule - make sure the info is present and understood before you make a purchase. Anyone making a module (or component) who doesn't understand that a decent pdf DS is a pre-requisite to an indication of quality can't be trusted to provide a product of any quality.

Comment: Most circuits you'll find will require an input voltage above the 2x4.2V=8.4V of your battery pack, the one you bought is no exception. You can easily see that from the fact that the board uses the same connection for charging and power output, hence you definitely need more voltage at the input than the batteries provide in total to force any charge into them.

Comment: I understand that JimmyB,i just thought maybe with 5V input it would first charge the first 3.7v battery,thus enough juice and then move on the next battery until the same task is done.Obviously that's not the case here.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specs
>
> - Short circuit protection
> - Overcharge protection
> - Over-discharge protection
> - Overcurrent protection
> - Overcharge Detection Voltage: 4.25-4.35V±0.05V
> - Over Discharge Detection Voltage: 2.3-3.0V±0.05V
> - Maximum Working Current: 3A
> - Transient Current: 5A
> - Operating Temperature: -40-50 degree
> - Internal Resistance: Less than 45m Ω
> - B+ B-: The interface of battery core
> - P+ P-: The connector of battery board
> - MB: The connection point between the batteries
> - B+: Battery V+ Positive
> - B-: Battery V- Negative
> - P+: Output / Charging V+
> - P-: Output / Charging V-
> - Size: Approx. 36x6x1mm/ 1.42" x 0.24" x 0.04"

---

Engineering Assumptions

> - Vsource min > for 2 cell OVP = 8.8V max.
> - Vsource max > due to Current limit and VI drop thus heat rise from losses

9Vdc 3A seems to be an optimal solution depending on cell ratings.

Comment: A seller replied and said that i would need to use a 8.4 Lipo charger.A 9v as you stated would be optimal so you are correct !